# State a diverging sequence $a_x$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[a_{f(x)}-a_x\right]=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, functions

> Is there a non-converging sequence $a_n$ such that 
>    for all strictly increasing $f:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow\mathbb{N}$
>
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[a_{f(n)}-a_n\right]=0\,?$$

Initially I thought $a_n=\log(n)$ might work, but it fails for $f(n)=kn$, $k\in \mathbb{N}, k\geq 2$.

I'm not sure how to go from here. Maybe we can use mod?

Comment: Let me see if I understood this correctly: you want an example of a divergent sequence $a_n$ and increasing function $f(n)$ such that the sequence $b_n=a_{f(n)}-a_n$ converges to $0$. Is that it?

$${}$$

Also, by 'divergent sequence' what exactly do you mean? A sequence that does not converge? A sequence whose absolute value becomes arbitrarily large?

Comment: This is unclear. Is the conclusion supposed to hold for each such $f?$

Comment: @ Fimpelliziere Yes, your first part is right. As for your second part, I want a sequence that does not converge, as in, they can either become arbitrarily large or oscillate.

Comment: @ zhw The conclusion should hold for every single possible f.

Comment: An initial observation is that with $a_0=0$ and $b_n=a_n-a_{n-1}$ we have

$$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^nb_k$$

So we may translate to a question on non-converging series. The limit condition states that, while the tail fails to converge, finite pieces of the tail --  no matter how large -- will always approach $0$ so long as the starting point of the tail increases. This does not look possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case there is no such example because:

$(a_{n})$ diverges $\Leftrightarrow \exists \epsilon>0, \forall N \in \mathbb{N}, \exists (p_{N} > q_{N} \geq N) \in \mathbb{N}^{2}, |a_{p_{N}}-a_{q_{N}}|>\epsilon$, i.e. if and only if $(a_{n})$ is not a Cauchy sequence.

You can pick $p_{N}, q_{N}$ such that $f(q_{N}) = p_{N}$ allows you to define a strictly increasing function from $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ (in order to prove this, you will need to use the fact that you can make the difference $p_{N}-q_{N}$ as large as you wish - if this were not true, you can prove that $(a_{n})$ would be Cauchy).

Now that's a contradiction since our stated limit cannot be $0$ with such a definition of $f$...

Comment: I think this answer can be made easier to parse, but it's correct. Good job!

Answer (score 0):

Let the sequence $a_n = n$ and $f(n) = n$.

Your sequence is divergent since $n$ goes to infinity. The series $a_n - f(n)$, however, is convergent since it is $0$ for any $n$ you pick

Comment: I am under the impression the property should hold for all increasing $f$. I'm not quite sure since the question seems poorly worded.

Comment: I doubt there'd be one for all increasing f. But maybe I don't know enough. Think about one with a really big f'(x)

Comment: I would be surprised too, but otherwise the question seems terribly uninteresting.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such sequence. Suppose for example $(a_n)$ is bounded and we're in the oscillating case. Then $a_n$ has at least two distinct subsequential limits, say $L_1,L_2\in \mathbb R.$ Let $f(n)$ strictly increase to $\infty$ along indices giving a limit of $L_1.$ Then $a_{f(n)} - a_n$ does not coverge, as it is the difference of a convergent sequence and a divergent sequence. This is just one case, but it should show the way in handling other cases.

Comment: What if $a_n$ has no convergent subsequence?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Suppose $a_n$ is not bounded above. Then there are positive integers $k_1 < k_2 < \cdots$ such that

$$a_{k_n}-a_n > n \, \text { for all } n.$$

Define $f(n) = k_n.$ Then $a_{f(n)} - a_n \to \infty.$

Comment: That works nicely.